# Show the set $S=\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)\in \mathbb{R}^5 \vert x_3^2e^{x_1+x_2^{100}}>2\}$ and another set is open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Can I please get feedback on proof below? Thank you!!

$\def\R{{\mathbb R}}$
Show the set $$S=\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)\in \R^5 \vert x_3^2e^{x_1+x_2^{100}}>2 \text{ and } x_3x_4 - x_5^2<-1\} \subset\R^5$$ is open.

$\textit{Proof.}$ Observe that $f\colon \R^5 \to \R$ as $f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5) = x_3^2e^{x_1+x_2^{100}}$ then $f$ is continuous, i.e., $(2, \infty)$ is open in $\R$. So, $f^{-1}(2,\infty)$ is open then $\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)\in \R^5 \vert x_3^2e^{x_1+x_2^{100}}>2\}$ is an open set. Now, let us define $g\colon \R^5 \to \R$ as $g(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)=x_3x_4 - x_5^2$, then we can see that $g$ is continuous as $(-\infty, -1)$ is open in $\R$. So, by definition, $g^{-1}((-\infty,-1))$ is open in $\R^5$. Thus, $\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)\in \R^5 \vert x_3x_4 -x_5^2 <-1\}$ is open. Now, since the intersection of open sets, particularly two, is open. Therefore, $$\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)\in \R^5 \vert x_3^2e^{x_1+x_2^{100}}>2\} \cap \{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)\in \R^5 \vert x_3x_4 - x_5^2<-1\}$$ is open, and we are done.

Comment: Your argument is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is correct. I would have given you the same proof! It is the intersection of two open sets and hence open.

Comment: Thank you, Kashif!